completionBlock in addDefaultHandlerForMethod not executed for real tvOS device
I'm using GCDWebServer for sending request and receiving response from my stream server. For that I am adding error handlers using 'GET' addDefaultHandlerForMethod. But the completionBlock() within this method is never called for real tvOS device. However I'm getting the call back for iOS device and iOS/tvOS simulators. Here's the sample code for implementation of the above function:
 private func configureHandlers() {
        server.addDefaultHandler(forMethod: "GET",
                                 request: GCDWebServerRequest.self,
                                 asyncProcessBlock: { [weak self] in
            self?.handleRequest($0, completion: $1)
        })
    }

I have tried their git page but they are closed for new issues.
